# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file on localhost

Tags: php, joomla, syntax-error

I had a website but is currently gone but I always had a back-up that worked on my hosting always.. I tried setting my website up on XAMPP but I keep getting the error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file.. I tried closing brackets but it didn't work. Can you guys please help me where the problem is? This is the index.php of my template where I'm getting it(backend of Joomla is doing fine):

http://pastebin.com/CzGbybYZ

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My guess? Short tags aren't enabled, meaning the `<? } ?>` is not recognised as your "end of code block". Use `<?php } ?>` instead.

Comment: NVM fixed myself! Thanks.

Comment: There is no `endforeach` in the code you have shared.